# Javascript regex problem

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

I need to make html pages where I want to share Ad space with other adsense users. I am trying to use javascript to find and replace adsense code using regex expression but I am stuck.

This is the piece of string I am trying to match.

> pub-111111111111111";
>
> /* 336x280, created 12/12/12 */
>
> google_ad_slot = "2222222222";

And this is the javascript containing regex expression that I tried (out of many other combination).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var html = document.body.innerHTML;
html = html.replace(/pub-([\d])*(";)\r(.)*\r(.)*([\d])(";)/i,'pub-444444444444444";google_ad_slot = "3333333333333";');
document.body.innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

But no luck. Anything RegEx other than **pub-([\d])*** part is not getting evaluated as I see using firebug.

Comment: [\d] means either \ or d which will never match. Try pub-(\d)*. Unless it's different in javascript regex, though I don't think it is.

Comment: @fy-tide This is not true. `[\d]` is equivalent to `[0-9]`

Comment: @fytide: The square brackets aren't *necessary* (and should be removed in the interest of reducing clutter) but `[\d]` means the same thing as `\d`.  This is true of every regex flavor I'm familiar with.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
/pub-([\d])*(";)\r(.)*\r(.)*([\d])(";)/i
```

to

```
/pub-(\d*)(";)\n(.*)\n(.*)(\d)(";)/gim
```

You need to keep the `*` token next to the thing it modifies, not outside of a capture group. Also, the `\n` is more likely to match your newlines than `\r`. Or you can use `[\r\n]+`

Not sure the above regex will capture *exactly* what you're looking to capture, but my comments should get you closer to the truth.